# Android: Answer phone call, play audio to caller, capture caller input

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been looking for the better part of a day for the answers but can only find parts of what I'm looking to do, so throwing it out here to see if anyone can answer, I'm not looking for code examples, just the right direction to look so that I can determine the viability of an idea, so classed or methods that could be used are perfect.

Would like to be able to do the following using Android M (API Level 23/minSdkVersion 23)

1. Automatically answer an inbound call on android (found multiple ways
   to do this)
2. Play dynamic audio("Please enter the following numbers n
   n n n") to the caller as a background service, so the person being called doesn't know there is even a call yet.
3. Capture the typed keys from the caller and validate(how do you capture inbound keys)
4. Ring the phone similar to a normal call if the caller entered the same numbers as stated in the dynamic audio

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you wanted to do this, you'd need to replace the phone's dialer and SIP app with your own.  There's no way to do it short of that.  Which is a LOT of work

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm aware of how to replace the dialer (pretty easy stuff with the right permissions etc.) now so sure about the requirement for the SIP please see the following app which does everything i'm trying to do i just don't know how they are doing it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youmail.android.vvm&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

2) this is the most important thing but cannot be achieved because it's not possible to "inject" Audio on the voicecall "channel", so the "solution" could be to play an audio file loudly that will be used from the Microphone, but in this way all Ambient Noise will be heard from the caller (privacy issue?).

3) keys use DTMF tones, so the solution is to record inbound Voice and analize the spectrum by searching right frequencies. Even this way is quite not-possible because Caller Ambient Noise could ruin the spectrum detector.

Comment: Thanks for the insight from your perspective. I'm pretty sure that your not correct as there are a few apps which already do EXACTLY what i'm asking i just don't know how they are doing it. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youmail.android.vvm&hl=en_US

Comment: I suppose you didn't read the description from that PlayStore link. The App is a NORMAL Visual Voicemail Manager where calls, texts and other things should be redirected/forwarded to a different phone number where there is a "real computer" that does all the job (auto-answer, play a message, record the call and send it to your visual voicemail manager App). The App does nothing more than display some data and few other easy things.

Comment: I guess you didn't install the app and have no clue what it really does as it DOESN'T just forward to carrier or other services and DOES play audio that is selected by the phone user or plays the callers name to the caller which the app gets from the name that is in the phone being called contact record.

Comment: I cannot install the App because "my carrier doesn't supports it" it's written in the Play Store. However the bottom text reports this: "(1) To use YouMail, you must forward missed calls to YouMail with carrier-specific forwarding codes.
(2) If YouMail doesn’t fit your needs, deactivate forwarding BEFORE you delete the app, otherwise your voicemail will NOT be re-routed back to your carrier", so the App works ONLY if we forward voicecall to another number. This procedure is common in all apps of this kind, and it means the App doesn't nothing by its own but all the work is done elsewhere